# How to force content to flow horizontally with scrollbar instead of the usual vertical way

Tags: css

I'm displaying content horizontally only, so as more content is loaded into the view I need the width to dynamically change to accomodate letting the scrollbar handle the scrolling. So right now this code below will only take content up to 4500px, anything after that it tries to break to a new line instead of continuing horizontally. Any ideas on how I can do this?

```
.container-scroll {
    width: 4500px;
    min-width: 3000px; 
    overflow-x:scroll;   
    position: relative;
    min-height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Uh, it seems so obvious that I assume I'm missing something, but you've set the width to 4500px in your first rule there.

Comment: Let us see the associated HTML as well please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need this CSS:

```
.container-scroll {
    width: auto;
    min-width: 100px; 
    overflow-x:scroll;   
    position: relative;
    min-height: 100%;
}​
```

Just specify required min-width and scrolling will handle rest.

Comment: Width being auto still doesn't work. It just breaks vertically when needed now.

Comment: Yes it seems to be, don't know why it's not working for me though. Must have some other css overriding something maybe

Comment: I put div's in there an it seems thats making it skip lines, how to stop a div from breaking? display:inline huh?

Comment: you can do display: inline and don't put any line breaks in content. http://jsfiddle.net/J7ZKB/8/

Comment: OK after all this time it's still not working. Unless I'm totally missing something, I'm about 90% sure I found why it's not working. I'm using razor engine from mvc. So in my view I call a foreach to loop through my model and load the content. I think it's the foreach statement that is stopping it from working correctly bc when I don't use the foreach statement, it works fine. I have no idea why though. I will make a new question for posting.

Comment: So adding white-space: nowrap; fixed the problem, all works good now. Thanks for the help btw.

Comment: You saved me hours with: `white-space: nowrap;` .. thanks buddy

Answer (score 1):

Don't specify a width on your container. Make sure the elements inside are `display: inline`.

Comment: Not specifying width sets width to auto by default which then will make my content load vertically instead of going horizontal. Have never been to sure what display inline does. I do have it set though.